# Код для аккордеона

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать аккордеон подобного плана, в тупик ставит не только код для javascript, но и что писать в html и css тоже не понимаю[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: уточните пожалуйста, что именно Вам непонятно? маловероятно, чтобы **все** было непонятно.

Comment: нужно создать три блока почти идентичных, а потом в javascript сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на один остальные становились скрытыми? вот код в javascript для меня и неясен

Comment: Вам на javascript или на Jquery тоже подойдет?

Comment: лучше чистый javascript

Comment: я когда-то писал аккордеон на чистом JS.. [Посмотрите код](https://github.com/zoltantothcom/vanilla-js-accordion) - он совсем краткий, а вот тут простой [пример](http://zoltantothcom.github.io/vanilla-js-accordion/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function toogle(e) {
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i += 1) {
    elems[i].childNodes[3].style.display = 'none';
  }
  e.childNodes[3].style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
div.test {
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
div.test>.header {
  padding: 5px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
div.test>.text {
  display:none;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<div class="test" onclick="toogle(this)">
  <div class="header">test</div>
  <div class="text">test1 test1 test1 test1 test1</div>
</div>
<div class="test" onclick="toogle(this)">
  <div class="header">test</div>
  <div class="text">test2 test2 test2 test2 test2</div>
</div>
<div class="test" onclick="toogle(this)">
  <div class="header">test</div>
  <div class="text">test3 test3 test3 test3 test3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: рады помочь) однако помните, что комментарии предназначены только для уточнения вопроса/ответа, а не для слов благодарности хоть они и приятны). [Не благодарите автора ответа в комментариях. Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: а что добавить в код, чтобы при запуске страницы элементы аккордеона не были в развернутом состоянии?

Comment: @Anastasiia так они сейчас в свернутом положении(элементы text каждого блока). Или Вы другое имеете ввиду?

Comment: в вашем примере все в свернутом, я скопировала ваш код, заменила только в var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('test'); test на свое значение, но при загрузке страницы все блоки развернуты, необходимо нажать на один из них, чтобы он остался, а остальные свернулись

Comment: @Anastasiia это потому, что Вы стили не изменили. В скопированных стилях замените `.test` на Ваше значение. Говоря более просто, пропишите стиль `display:none;` для Вашего значения класса.

Comment: точно, а как сделать так, чтобы один всегда оставался открыт при загрузке?

Comment: @Anastasiia `div.test:first-child>.text {display:block !important;}`